# How to verify if a security update has been applied to Azure App Service OS?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-security

I would like to verify if security update [CVE-2020-0796](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2020-0796), released 4/13/2020, has been applied to the App Service OS that is running my app.

I have read this article [OS and runtime patching in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-patch-os-runtime) that Azure updates their OS monthly, which aligns to the monthly Patch Tuesday schedule. These updates are applied automatically, in a way that guarantees the high-availability SLA of Azure services. However it only explained how to look up the versions of Windows and of the language runtime that are running my apps. It did not explain how to verify that a specific patch was applied.

I have also read [Demystifying the magic behind App Service OS updates](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/01/18/Demystifying-the-magic-behind-App-Service-OS-updates.html). It says that the "typical time for completing updates worldwide is about 10 business days".

How can verify for certain that security update CVE-2020-0796 has been applied on my App Service OS?

Thank you in advance for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way probably how to pull installed KBs, but we do install monthly security patches regularly. Since this is 2018 related, the patch has to be installed already and for a long time now.

**Also, the security rollups go over each other, so any subsequent can supersede the previous.**

Comment: You said "no easy way". Is it impossible from my end? Is it possible to make a request (for a fee if necessary) to MSFT to check if a specific patch was installed, and if so how do I do it?